# How to determine if a user is a member of an admin group in Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm new to using Flask, so apologies for what might be a basic question.

I'm working on a new Flask application that has multiple tables in a database.  There is a table for storing the users information (name, password, enabled).  Another table holds the group names and if it is an admin group (type is boolean).  A third table relates the user to the group(s) they are a member of, since they could be a member of more than one.  Here is the relevant code from models.py

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
username = db.Column(db.String(10), index=True, unique=True)
password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
active_user = db.Column(db.Boolean)
group_ids = db.relationship('GroupMembers', backref='user', lazy='dynamic' )

def __repr__(self):
    return 'User {} | Active {}'.format(self.username, self.active_user)

def set_password(self, password):
    self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

def check_password(self, password):
    return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

def check_admin(self):
    group_ids = self.group_ids.all()
    for row in group_ids:
        group = Group.query.get(int(row.gid))
        if group.admin_rights:
            return True
    return False

class Group(db.Model):
gid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
groupname = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True, unique=True)
admin_rights = db.Column(db.Boolean)
group_members = db.relationship('GroupMembers', backref='members', lazy='dynamic')

def __repr__(self):
    return 'ID: {} | Name: {} | Admin: {}'.format(self.gid, self.groupname, self.admin_rights)

def is_admin_group(self, gid):
    _group = self.query.get(int(gid))
    return _group.admin_rights

class GroupMembers(db.Model):
__table_args__ = ( db.UniqueConstraint('gid', 'uid'), )
id = db.Column(db.Integer, prmary_key=True)
gid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, db.ForeignKey('group.gid'))
uid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

def __repr__(self):
    return "{}.{}".format(self.gid, self.uid)
```

I'm trying to find the best way to determine if a user is a member of a admin group (group.admin_rights == True).  The 'check_admin' function in 'User' works, but I'm unsure of how to call this from within the html templates.  Could this be called using something like

{% if current_user.check_admin() %}

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your check_admin() is working fine, you can pass the additional check_admin flag like this

```
return render_template('sample_page.html', admin=check_admin())
```

and in the Jinja template, you can simply check for an admin user with:

```
{% if admin %}
```